# std::sort with local type Compare

Tags: c++, gcc

The following example

```
// file mysort.cc
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>

void mysort (const char**tab, unsigned size) {
  std::vector<int> vecix;
  vecix.resize(size);
  struct CompareIndex {
    const char**t;
    CompareIndex(const char**p) : t(p) {};
    bool operator() (int l, int r)  {
      return strcmp(t[l], t[r])<0;
    }
  };
  CompareIndex compix(tab);
  for (unsigned ix=0; ix<size; ix++) vecix[ix] = ix;
  std::stable_sort(vecix.begin(), vecix.end(), compix);
  std::vector<const char*> vecstr;
  vecstr.resize(size);
  for (unsigned ix=0; ix<size; ix++) vecstr[ix] = tab[vecix[ix]];
  for (unsigned ix=0; ix<size; ix++) tab[ix] = vecstr[ix];
}
```

fails to compile (using GCC 4.8.2 on Debian/Sid/x86-64 in C++03 standard)

```
mysort.cc: In function 'void mysort(const char**, unsigned int)':
mysort.cc:19:58: error: no matching function for call to 
      'stable_sort(std::vector<int>::iterator, 
                   std::vector<int>::iterator, 
                   mysort(const char**, unsigned int)::CompareIndex&)'
   std::stable_sort(vecix.begin(), vecix.end(), compix);
                                                      ^


In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                 from mysort.cc:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5682:5: note: 
       template<class _RAIter, class _Compare>
                void std::stable_sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)
     stable_sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5682:5: note:   
    template argument deduction/substitution failed:
mysort.cc: In substitution of 'template<class _RAIter, class _Compare>
     void std::stable_sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)
     [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >;
           _Compare = mysort(const char**, unsigned int)::CompareIndex]':
mysort.cc:19:58:   required from here
mysort.cc:19:58: error: template argument for
    'template<class _RAIter, class _Compare> 
         void std::stable_sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)'
     uses local type 'mysort(const char**, unsigned int)::CompareIndex'
       std::stable_sort(vecix.begin(), vecix.end(), compix);
                                                          ^
mysort.cc:19:58: error:   trying to instantiate
            'template<class _RAIter, class _Compare>
                     void std::stable_sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)'
```

The above was compiled with [GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) using

```
  g++ -Wall -c mysort.cc
```

I am getting the same error with

```
  g++ -std=c++03 -Wall -c mysort.cc
```

or with

```
  g++ -std=c++98 -Wall -c mysort.cc
```

but no errors with

```
  g++ -std=c++11 -c mysort.cc
```

given that my `g++ -v` is a `gcc version 4.8.2 (Debian 4.8.2-12)`

but with [Clang/LLVM 3.4](http://llvm.org/releases/3.4/docs/ReleaseNotes.html) compiling with

```
  clang++ -Wall -c mysort.cc
```

I'm getting only a warning:

```
  mysort.cc:19:7: warning: template argument uses local 
                  type 'CompareIndex'
                [-Wlocal-type-template-args]
  std::stable_sort(vecix.begin(), vecix.end(), compix);
  ^~~
  1 warning generated.
```

(and I still get only a warning not an error when passing `-std=c++03` or `-std=c++98` to `clang++` but no warnings with `clang++ -std=c++11`)

so my question is: why the error by GCC and the warning by Clang? Is my code legal and without undefined behavior (w.r.t. the C++03 standard)? Should I make my `CompareIndex` a global `struct` in my compilation unit?

#### motivations

Of course, this is a silly way to sort an array of C strings. 
The real code is a bit different. In fact, I am trying to use `std::stable_sort` in my [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) plugin (a domain specific language to extend and customize GCC). MELT is generating C++ code and has a *copying* [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) (so pointers are moved by the GC). Hence, I need to sort using an array of indexes: the compare function in fact calls a MELT closure (which could trigger the copying GC at arbitrary moment), so I need to sort by indexes (and not by raw pointers). I want to keep the C++ code generated by MELT conforming to the C++ standard (03 or 98) required to compile GCC.

#### work-around

Thanks to [juanchopanza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21201894/841108) I've solved the issue by moving the declaration of `CompareIndex` at global scope before `mysort`.

<sup>I just committed the svn revision 206748 of the MELT branch of GCC; its file `gcc/melt/warmelt-base.melt` contains now a `multiple_sort_new` MELT function (to replace `multiple_sort` when it is working well) using `std::stable_sort`, and a global `Melt_Sort_Compare_Index` class in the generated C++ code.</sup>

Comment: IIRC in C++03 you cannot use local types in std lib templates, and this restriction has been lifted in C++11. It would be interesting to compile with `std=c++98` and `std=c++11`.

Comment: Would moving the `CompareIndex` type at global level (before `mysort` function) would make my code C++03 standard conforming and without undefined behavior?

Comment: @junachopanza: Please make that an answer so I could accept it. (in addition I'll be delighted if you could quote the standard prohibiting that).

Comment: OK, I found the relevant quote from the C++03 standard and added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using local types as template arguments is not allowed in C++03.

From ISO/IEC 14882,  **14.3.1 Template type arguments [temp.arg.type]**:

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type
>   compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a
>   template-argument for a template type-parameter.

The example given is along these lines:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo {};

void foo()
{
  struct Bar {};
  Foo<Bar> b1;   // error: local type used as template-argument
  Foo<Bar*> x4;  // error: pointer to local type used as template-argument
}
```

This restriction has been lifted in C++11.