# Unable to resolve template in STL sort for vector of pairs

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I've tried to sort a vector of pairs, using approaches outlined in [How do I sort a vector of pairs based on the second element of the pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279854/how-do-i-sort-a-vector-of-pairs-based-on-the-second-element-of-the-pair), but
my compiler can't seem to resolve my templates.

The problem region looks approximately as follows:

```
template <typename T, typename Tds1, typename Tds2>
void myClass<T,Tds1,Tds2>::myMethod(myTemplateParam<T> &in, 
                                    myTemplateParam<T> &out) {

  typedef std::pair <Tds2, T> labelDistPair;
  std::vector< labelDistPair > labelRanks;

  struct sort_pairs {
    bool operator()(const std::pair<Tds2, T> &left,
                    const std::pair<Tds2, T> &right)
                    {return left.second < right.second;}
   };

  //...
  //Fill in labelRanks - a vector of <float, double> pairs
  //...


  std::sort(labelRanks.begin(), labelRanks.end(), sort_pairs());

  }
 }
```

The most relevant part of my error message seems to be:

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5474:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
...
error:   trying to instantiate ‘template void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare)’

Does this make sense? (I've gotten a similar error when I tried using
a lambda function as the comparison function)

Comment: Are you sure that's your exact code? Looks fine to me. I put together a similar example and it compiled just fine. What argument are you giving for `Tds2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably not compiling with a C++11-capable compiler (or you haven't enabled the feature). As seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201685/stdsort-with-local-type-compare), C++03 doesn't allow a local type as a template argument (i.e. you need to move your sorting functor out into namespace scope.)